# Can't select a column specifycally in Sqllite, but I see if I select all Columns?

Tags: sqlite

A simple question that distracts me as can't figure it out.

From SqlLite Client once I do a select:

```
select cp.Column1, cp.Column2, cp.Column3, count(*) from TableOne cp
Group by Column1, Column2
```

I get an error:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: no such column: cp.Column3
At line 1:
```

Once I do:

```
select cp.Column1, cp.Column2, cp.* from TableOne cp
Group by Column1, Column2
```

I see Column3 in the results.

Is this issue with the DB or an issue with the select query?

Comment: Check for leading or trailing spaces at the name of Column3

Comment: Perfect! The DB column is set with spaces, though is there a change I can group by them?

Comment: You can use double quotes or square brackets around the name like: `"Column3 "` or `[Column3 ]`

Comment: But it would be better to rename the column: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

Comment: Thank you! I am new, hence this was valuable. Ohh so happy! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the space as per comments.